# Plotting complex numbers

Tags: complex-numbers

How to plot G and arg(G) when
G(w) = 1/(1+iw)(1+ 2iw)

I don't know how to do this one.can you please help me?I plotted the graph for G. But I'm not sure about my answer. Can you please produce the graphs of this

Comment: I think this can help you. ...
http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/7275/how-can-i-generate-this-domain-coloring-plot

Comment: You expression is unclear. Do you mean the Möbius function defined by $G(w)=\dfrac{1+ 2iw}{1+iw}$ ?

Comment: Besides, "plotting" a complex variable function is a perfectly ambiguous expression. If it is homework, ask your lecturer what he/she means by that.